# ASP.NET Core Razor pages multiple routes for 1 page leads to wrong formaction

Tags: asp.net, url-routing, razor-pages

My idea is to have a single Razor page handle two different urls.
The first url handles a normal list page, with a top menu and background image. The second url handles the same list page with all the same logic, but it is used in popup dialogs. In the popup dialog it shouldn't have the menu or the background image, hence the two urls to make this distinction.

I've created 2 routes for a single page, which points to /Contacts/List.cshtml, as follows:

```
options.Conventions.AddPageRouteModelConvention("/contacts/list", model => {
        model.Selectors.Clear(); // remove default route
        model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel() { AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel() { Template = "/contacts/list", Name = "normal" } });
        model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel() { AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel() { Template = "/contacts/list/popup", Name = "popup" } });
});
```

So far so good, both routes work. I can get the current Selector name correctly by using

```
var endpoint = HttpContext.GetEndpoint() as RouteEndpoint;
var routeNameMetadata = endpoint?.Metadata.OfType<RouteNameMetadata>().SingleOrDefault();
var routeName = routeNameMetadata?.RouteName;
```

However, every form element on the page is pointing to the wrong selector.
For example, if I go to /contacts/list, and I put in a submit button as follows:

```
<input id="searchButton" type="submit" asp-page-handler="Search" />
```

it is rendered to have a formaction to the wrong route selector (the popup route in stead of the normal route):

```
<input id="searchButton" type="submit" formaction="/contacts/list/popup?handler=Search">
```

I cannot figure out why this is happening.

I have a workaround by using /contact/list?type=normal and /contact/list?type=popup but I think different urls is more elegant.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?